# React / Sails.js Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sails.js, babeljs, html-webpack-plugin

So I´m trying to set up a React/Sails project and I just set the webpack config but its messing with the pluging/preset error.

The versions are correct (above 7.*). I´ve already read a lot of similar issues but none of them helped me.

ERROR in ./assets/src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.

Here is the webpack file:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    entry: './assets/src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/.tmp/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        test: /\.css$/
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'assets/src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

And here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-desk",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "sails": "^1.2.3",
    "sails-hook-apianalytics": "^2.0.3",
    "sails-hook-organics": "^0.16.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.1.1",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "grunt": "1.0.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "htmlhint": "0.11.0",
    "lesshint": "6.3.6",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  },
```

The .babelrc file

```
 {
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "react"]
 }
```

The index.js (just in case)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>myDesk</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='root'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your babel config

Comment: Oh, i forgot. There it goes.

Comment: I think you are using old versions of babel presets which are not compatible with babel 7. It's not babel-preser-env anymore, it's babel/env

Comment: Do you mean @babel/preset-env? @Patrick Hund

Comment: I´ve installed the @babel/presets-env and changed it to "presets": ["@babel/presets-env", "react"]. But the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem before and I solved it using this config:

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
```

Try to install it. It should work. You need babel-loader 7 instead of 8. Because the 8th version will not work.

Otherwise take a look here: 
https://github.com/TahaBoulehmi/FullStack

You will find there all the needed configurations. You can clone the project and start working on it. It is an empty Sails and React project that I configured before to help me save some time whenever I want to start a new project.
I hope it helps.